# How can I put text upon a css element (in this case: a coloured segment of a circle)?

Tags: html, css

I've been working for days now to make a kind of "Wheel of Fortune" in HTML and CSS. The wheel and the colors are already perfect, but now I have to put a text in every segment, and I can't do that. I've already tried with ::before and ::after, but I'm doing something wrong I think.

Can someone help me?

Best regards,

Comment: For anyone to be able to assist we would need you to add some code. You should also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ideally text should be part of your HTML document **not** CSS.

Comment: But, it's the first time I'm using this, and I don't know how to add my code...